# Repeating a format/layout in TableView

Tags: android, android-layout, android-tablelayout

I'm learning Android and am currently trying to design an app that would consist of users with posts, which would in turn have comments and likes. I was able to figure out how to do posts and to keep track of the "author" for each post. However, I've been having trouble with the comments aspect of it.

I am currently using a TableView for the FeedActivity (the activity that shows all the posts and their respective comments and likes), and am able to show all the posts. **Is it possible to have a layout xml file that would repeat the same format for each "cell" in TableView?** By "same format", I mean show the post, its own comments/likes, and two buttons for adding a comment and liking. Furthermore, I cannot hardcode the number of these "cells" I would need, since theoretically multiple users can post many posts and I would not know how many at the time of development.

[This](http://www.mkyong.com/android/android-tablelayout-example/) was helpful for me, but I would like to have the two layouts (top and bottom of the red line) be the same, with different button functionality.
I have also tried to consult [this](http://www.vogella.com/tutorials/AndroidListView/article.html), but wasn't sure which part specifically applied to my case.

Any help would be appreciated! Please let me know if I should clarify anything.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

as far as I have understood that you want to use the same layout for multiple data in a layout. So if I am right you can use a listview with custom list view adapter to show each row as same with different data.

See this tutorial to learn about how to use custom list adapter.
http://www.learn-android-easily.com/2013/06/listview-with-custom-adapter.html

For every row you can use your single tableview to show the information.

Comment: Thanks, I'll try this out and see if I can get my app to work!